# Disable checkout if all products do not share same tag Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a custom checkout experience in my Shopify store that I only want to allow if all products in the cart contain the tag "test"

This is the function I currently have, which seems to only work with a single item in the cart.

```
  function productTags() {
    {%- assign tagEnabled = false -%}
    return {
      {%- for item in cart.items -%}
        {%- if item.product.tags contains 'test' -%}
          "{{ item.product.tags }}": {{ item.quantity | json }}
          {%- assign tagEnabled = true -%} 
        {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
    };
  }
```

this line ( "{{ item.product.tags }}": {{ item.quantity | json }}) is only there for display in the console when testing this. I can remove that if necessary.

How can I expand this to look for all item tags in the cart, and only assign the tagEnabled variable to true if all of them have the same tag?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to mix Liquid with Javascript, which can make coding confusing. I would recommend splitting your code into two parts: one where you collect your Liquid variables and assign them to Javascript variables (and I see you are using the `json` filter to do that already, which is awesome - that filter guarantees that your variable output will be in a Javascript-legal format), and the second part where you write your Javascript code without any Liquid brackets getting in the way.  (This is especially helpful if you are using a code editor with any syntax or error highlighting)

Let me know if the following helps you get the information you need:

```
// The Liquid filter 'map' lets you drill into nested object properties. We can use this to get an array of tag arrays.
// The JSON Liquid filter will turn any Liquid variable into a legal Javascript variable.
const itemProductTags = {{ cart.items | map: 'product'| map: 'tags' | json }}

// Check on our variables
console.log('All product tag arrays', itemProductTags)
console.log('Results of tagCheck()', tagCheck(itemProductTags, 'test') )

function tagCheck(tagsList, targetTag){
  // Checks to see if the targetTag appears in all, some or none of the tag arrays.
  // tagsList will be an array of arrays

  var targetInAny = false;
  var targetInAll = true;

  for(var i=0; i<tagsList.length; i++){
    var tags = tagsList[i];
    if(tags.indexOf(targetTag) != -1){
      // Found the tag - this targetTag appears in at least one product-tag list
      targetInAny = true;
    }
    else{
     // Did not find the tag - this targetTag is NOT in every product-tag list
     targetInAll = false;
    }
  }

  // Returns an object specifying if we found the target in any, all or none of the lists
  return { targetInAny: targetInAny, targetInAll: targetInAll, targetInNone: !targetInAny }
}
```

Comment: I think this gives me what I need, this is a great help! If I could ask one more, very noobish question that would be amazing. I want to basically call my inject() function only if the targetInAll is true. What do you think is the best call to call that function, and store the result of targetInAll in a liquid variable?

Comment: Liquid code is processed server-side to create the HTML/CSS/Javascript files that are served to the client's computer. Once those files are downloaded, the client's browser will run the supplied code.  Long story short, you can pass Liquid variables into Javascript (which happens at the server level) but you cannot use Javascript to assign variables in Liquid (since Javascript runs client-side).  That said, there are multiple ways that you can render your desired section using Javascript...

Comment: ... the easiest of which may be to use the new Section Rendering API (https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/sections/section-rendering-api) which allows you to use Javascript to get the rendered HTML content for a section based on the section name.

Comment: Note that you can use this method to get the HTML for a section regardless of whether that section has been included on any given page. This allows you to simply make the section and not directly include it anywhere - you would access the rendered content through the javascript request instead.

Comment: Dave B... I gotta hand it to you. You respodned here before anyone did on the Shopify forums. It was extremely helpful and useful and provided me the exact solution for the problem at hand. Thank You greatly and hope you have a good weekend.

Comment: Just happened to be in the right place at the right time.  Glad I could help, good luck with your project!